# RetrieveSalesforceObjects by SFID Custom Ojbect

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have created the below AmpScript to be placed on an email, however l am unsure how to retrieve the SFID dynamically when sending via a Entry Event:

The object is called 'Website' what do l replace the "010101010" with?

I want to send the email to the Contact associated to the Website record with the Username and Password sitting on the Website Record.

Thanks

```
%%[
var @DesignBreif, @DesignBreifRow
Set @DesignBreif= RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Website__c', 'Questionnaire_Password__c, Questionnaire_Username__c, Primary_Contact_First_Name__c', 'Id', '=', "010101010")

Set @DesignBreifRow = ROW(@DesignBreif,1)
set @DesignBreifUsername = Field(@DesignBreifRow, 'Questionnaire_Username__c')
set @DesignBreifPassword = Field(@DesignBreifRow, 'Questionnaire_Password__c')
]%%

<p>Username <code>%%=v(@DesignBreifUsername)=%%</code></p>
<p>Password <code>%%=v(@DesignBreifPassword)=%%</code></p>
```

Comment: Is there a lookup field in website__c that relates back to the contacts object?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to start with your contact record and find out the website a given contact is associated with. I'm assuming on the Salesforce Contact object, you will have a lookup or master detail field for Website.

1. Use RetrieveSalesforceObjects on Contact object, use the contact ID and get the website name or code from this object. The Contact ID can be referenced from _subscriberkey.
2. Use the Website name or code retrieved from step 1 to insert the value where you mention "010101010". this should give you the details you need for the rest of your code.